# Manjaro ARM locking up after entering password for user on login screen - but root can login

Tags: login, manjaro, plasma

#### Prelude

- New to having a Linux distribution as an OS on anything I own.
- Brand new to any Linux OS with a GUI.
- Searched here on U&LSE, found questions that were tangentially similar, but nothing exactly. Closest to my issue was [Manjaro: Can’t log in. Screen freezes after I enter my password](https://unix.stackexchange.com/q/441861/497600), but things mentioned in those answers did not exactly seem to pertain.

#### Setup

- Laptop: Pinebook Pro
- Linux Distribution: Manjaro ARM (Pinebook Pro came with it installed)

#### Play-by-play

- Everything seemed to be working fine. I've been using this laptop daily for a few weeks with no major issues.
- Was logged in, mostly using web browsers
- Did a mass update of Manjaro and "gazillions" of other items that the system indicated needing updated.
- Some time after everything updated, used Ark to extract an archived folder to the desktop. This is my file that I archived and I have extracted folders exactly like this from that file at least a half-dozen times with no issues.

  - The extraction failed (don't recall the error)
- Got a popup which stated that Plasma crashed/died *(don't recall specifics)*
- Clicked [Pine button] *{like the [Window] button or the [Apple] button (or whatever the button is on a Mac)}* + L to try to lock the screen, intending to click Restart from the lock screen

  - Got a popup which stated that locking crashed/died/failed/would not work *(don't recall specifics)*
- Held down power button to shut down

### Issue

- On power up, as usual it went to my main (and only) non-*root* user login screen
- Able to enter password

  - After entering and clicking 'Enter', nothing happened
- Able to  move cursor (I use the track pad), but clicking has no effect
- Just sits there indefinitely

#### Further Info

- After holding down power button to shut down again, and then starting back up, if I don't enter a password I can click on "Restart" or "Shut down" and they work
- I can also click to log in as a different user

  - I **am** able to log in as *root*

#### Postlude

If it is possible for someone to know how to fix this issue directly, I'm all for it.  As a "Plan B", I just need to retrieve some files from my user account and save them externally; then if I need to, I can wipe the machine and start from scratch (I would need to be pointed to help for that, though).

Answer (score 0):

I assume that this is a rookie issue, but for folks like me who *are* rookies and don't already know all of this:

#### tl;dr

I was out of disk space.

#### Details

- As stated in the question, upon power up or reboot the GUI login screen would appear but would freeze after entering the correct password.
- If I tried this before freeze up, I was able to use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> (or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F3</kbd> or <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F4</kbd> or ...) to open a TTY/virtual terminal/however-it-is-properly-referenced and log in that way. *[I had to discover that I could even attempt to do this, as I was unaware before trying to research my original issue.]*
- Using this terminal session, I was able to find the files that I wanted to "save".
- I began trying to figure out how to mount my external drive in order to move said files.
- At some point, an attempt to create a new directory (or maybe copy a file locally) failed with an error that mentioned being *out of space*.
- After ultimately mounting my drive, copying files, and unmounting my drive, I locally deleted one large directory of files.
- Upon restart, I was able to log in via the GUI login screen

---

So while most seasoned Linux users might have known the issue immediately, without something explicitly telling me when trying to log in that I was out of space, I had no idea - hence my question.

Comment: That's the reason why 5% of space on ext2/3/4 filesystems are reserved for root.