# How to configure multiple monitors with DVI and HDMI connections with CentOS 7

Tags: centos, xorg, multi-monitor, hdmi

I am trying to configure dual monitors on a custom built machine with an Intel i7-7700K CPU, a NVIDIA 1080-Ti GPU, and a CentOS 7 operating system. I have no problem booting with the primary monitor connected to the DVI port, but activating the secondary monitor with the HDMI port has been a struggle. After reading [this post](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25120/xrandr-doesnt-detect-monitor-on-hdmi-port) I tried updating the `/etc/X11/xorg.conf` for the GPU with the following lines:

```
Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BusID "PCI:01:00:0"
    Option "NoLogo" "true"
    Option "UseEDID" "true"
    Option "ConnectedMonitor" "DFP"
EndSection
```

I did not reboot the computer at this point. Just saved the file and switched the power on the secondary display on and off.

[This post](https://superuser.com/questions/259583/no-signal-on-monitor-after-plug-it-to-a-linux-box) also points to xorg.conf as being part of the solution, but so far I haven't had any luck. I've opened up my displays panel and only my primary monitor is being detected. In case it's relevant information, I have also installed all NVIDIA drivers and configured CUDA on this build.

Any thoughts? How do I get this secondary monitor up and running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Open a command terminal and then run 'sudo nvidia-settings' .  This should open up the nvidia setup application where you can fix your video settings to support multiple monitors and then reboot and you should be up and running.

Comment: I switched to Fedora awhile back so I haven't had the chance to try this, but I'm upvoting it because it seems reasonable. Thanks for the time!