# xrandr does not detect monitors

Tags: xorg, nvidia, multi-monitor, xrandr

I had 3 "NVIDIA NVS 300 Dual-VGA" with 6 monitors. I switched to 2 "NVIDIA Quadro NVS 450" cards for 8 monitors.

I had packages installed

```
xorg-server
xorg-xinit
xf86-input-evdev
xf86-input-mouse
xf86-input-keyboard
mesa
xorg-xrandr
xf86-video-nouveau
xf86-video-vesa
xf86-video-fbdev
```

I removed

```
xf86-video-nouveau xf86-video-vesa xf86-video-fbdev
```

I installed

```
nvidia-340xx
```

I have 2 "NVIDIA Quadro NVS 450" cards connected to 8 monitors. Only detects 2 monitors

```
xrandr -q
Screen 0: minimum 8 x 8, current 3840 x 1080, maximum 8192 x 8192
DP-0 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-1 disconnected (normal left inverted right x axis y axis)
DP-2 connected primary 1920x1080+0+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    74.91    59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93  
DP-3 connected 1920x1080+1920+0 (normal left inverted right x axis y axis) 527mm x 296mm
   1920x1080     60.00*+  74.97    74.91    59.94    50.00    60.00    50.04  
   1680x1050     59.95  
   1440x900      59.89  
   1280x1024     75.02    60.02  
   1280x800      59.81  
   1280x720      60.00    59.94    50.00  
   1152x864      75.00  
   1024x768      75.03    70.07    60.00  
   800x600       75.00    60.32    56.25  
   720x576       50.00  
   720x480       59.94  
   640x480       75.00    59.94    59.93
```

My xorg.conf generated from nvidia-xconfig:

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 340.108  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-01)  Wed Dec 11 15:13:33 PST 2019

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Unknown"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

I have:

```
lspci -k | grep -A 2 -E "(VGA|3D)"
05:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 450] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0619
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
--
06:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 450] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0619
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
--
09:00.0 3D controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 450] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0619
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
--
0a:00.0 VGA compatible controller: NVIDIA Corporation G98 [Quadro NVS 450] (rev a1)
    Subsystem: NVIDIA Corporation Device 0619
    Kernel driver in use: nvidia
```

I changed my xorg.conf to ↓ according to help → [xrandr doesn't detect monitor on hdmi port](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/25120/xrandr-doesnt-detect-monitor-on-hdmi-port)

```
# nvidia-xconfig: X configuration file generated by nvidia-xconfig
# nvidia-xconfig:  version 340.108  (buildmeister@swio-display-x64-rhel04-01)  Wed Dec 11 15:13:33 PST 2019

Section "ServerLayout"
    Identifier     "Layout0"
    Screen      0  "Screen0"
    InputDevice    "Keyboard0" "CoreKeyboard"
    InputDevice    "Mouse0" "CorePointer"
EndSection

Section "Files"
    ModulePath      "/usr/lib/nvidia"
    ModulePath      "/usr/lib/xorg/modules"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Mouse0"
    Driver         "mouse"
    Option         "Protocol" "auto"
    Option         "Device" "/dev/psaux"
    Option         "Emulate3Buttons" "no"
    Option         "ZAxisMapping" "4 5"
EndSection

Section "InputDevice"
    # generated from default
    Identifier     "Keyboard0"
    Driver         "kbd"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor0"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Idek Iiyama PL2493H"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor1"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Idek Iiyama PL2493H"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor2"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Idek Iiyama PL2493H"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection

Section "Monitor"
    Identifier     "Monitor3"
    VendorName     "Unknown"
    ModelName      "Idek Iiyama PL2493H"
    HorizSync       28.0 - 33.0
    VertRefresh     43.0 - 72.0
    Option         "DPMS"
EndSection


Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device0"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName       "NVS: 450"
    BusID           "PCI:05:00:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device1"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName       "NVS: 450"
    BusID           "PCI:06:00:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device2"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName       "NVS: 450"
    BusID           "PCI:09:00:0"
EndSection

Section "Device"
    Identifier     "Device3"
    Driver         "nvidia"
    VendorName     "NVIDIA Corporation"
    BoardName       "NVS: 450"
    BusID           "PCI:0a:00:0"
EndSection

Section "Screen"
    Identifier     "Screen0"
    Device         "Device0"
    Monitor        "Monitor0"
    DefaultDepth    24
    SubSection     "Display"
        Depth       24
    EndSubSection
EndSection
```

After I remove xorg.conf it still doesn't detect all monitors. Where is the problem?

My Xorg.0.log → https://pastebin.com/rF1vRvXC

My dmesg → https://pastebin.com/H0PmX6zy

Comment: I replaced it with 4 x NVIDIA NVS 310 cards and it works